# How To Measure Amount Of Shake On iOS Device In Swift?

Tags: ios, swift3, core-motion

I'm using CoreMotion to acquire device motion measurements in an app.  I can get acceleration x y z, roll, pitch, yaw, gyro data, etc.

But what I'm trying to measure is shake i.e. how much the device is moving and to set thresholds for when a device has moved a large amount in any direction.  I've found that the measurements I'm getting back are super sensitive and I don't know how to use it all correctly.

> Note: I know about detecting the shake gesture and that is not what I'm asking - I'm asking for the correct way to measure the amount of shake and display it.

Sample of code I'm using from DeviceMotion:

```
        if let deviceMotion = motionManager.deviceMotion {
        let quat = deviceMotion.attitude.quaternion;
        var qRoll = radiansToDegrees(radians: atan2(2*(quat.y*quat.w - quat.x*quat.z), 1 - 2*quat.y*quat.y - 2*quat.z*quat.z)) ;
        var qPitch = radiansToDegrees(radians: atan2(2*(quat.x*quat.w + quat.y*quat.z), 1 - 2*quat.x*quat.x - 2*quat.z*quat.z));
        var qYaw = radiansToDegrees(radians: asin(2*quat.x*quat.y + 2*quat.w*quat.z));

        let orientation = deviceMotion.attitude
        var roll = radiansToDegrees(radians: orientation.roll)
        var pitch = radiansToDegrees(radians: orientation.pitch)
        var yaw = radiansToDegrees(radians: orientation.yaw)
}
```

And using accelerometer:

```
        if motionManager.isAccelerometerAvailable {
        motionManager.startAccelerometerUpdates(to: OperationQueue.current!, withHandler: { accelerometerData, error in
            if let acceleration = accelerometerData?.acceleration {
                print("ACCELEROMETER X: " + acceleration.x.description)
                print("ACCELEROMETER Y: " + acceleration.y.description)
                print("ACCELEROMETER Z: " + acceleration.z.description)
        })
    }
```

What is the correct way to use the measurements from CoreMotion to measure how much a device is shaking?

Comment: What is your use case?

Comment: A few but my interest is finding out more about CoreMotion and how to measure shakeyness but a use case is to put the device on an object and measure how much it is shaking.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on your exact use case, but if you want to determine the amount of shake, calculate a motion delta. Determine the maximum and minimum values for one of the device motion attributes within a given period of time, and use that value as an approximation of "shakiness".

For example, you could measure the `yaw` of the device over a period of 5 seconds. Keep track of the minimum and maximum values, and take the difference between them. More shaking will result in a larger value.

Again it depends on your exact use case, but you could also take a combination of device motion attributes and their motion deltas. If you knew that the motion was consistent over time (like a machine shaking back and forth), you could try to find local min/max values and average them over a period of time.

Comment: I don't think it's specific to use case.  Any use case from a seismograph to measuring vibration of a machine would need to calculate how much movement is measured for any position of the device i.e. face down, face up, on it side on it's bottom.  I'm seeing that the values returned are quite sensitive and there is a lot of flicker in the values even when the phone is not moved at all.